# highest and lowest value in each (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code return:

```
0: 100,
1: 10,
2: 120,
3: 1
```

I need to catch the highest and lowest value. Is there any way to do it?. I need a `var min = 1` and `var max = 120`

```
var activeChoose = $('.filter--active-container').find('span[data-filter-param*="sFilterProperties"]');
  activeChoose.each(function (index, value) {
    if (!$($('.filter--active-container').find('span[data-filter-param*="sFilterProperties"]'))[index].attributes.style) {
      $(this).each(function (fakeIndex, value) {
        console.log(index + ': ' + parseInt(value.innerText));
      })
}});
```

Comment: where are you willing to use min max value?

Comment: `Math.max(1, 3, 2)` and `Math.min(1, 3, 2)`?

Comment: I would like to save this numbers in values

Comment: provide an example though it may have error.

Comment: There are so many answers on how to find a minimum and maximum on StackOverflow. Did you not find them??

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
var activeChoose = $('.filter--active-container').find('span[data-filter-param*="sFilterProperties"]');

var minVal = 0;
var maxVal = 0;
activeChoose.each(function (index, value) {

if (!$($('.filter--active-container').find('span[data-filter-param*="sFilterProperties"]'))[index].attributes.style) {
    $(this).each(function (fakeIndex, value) {
        if(minVal > parseInt(value.innerText)){
            minVal = parseInt(value.innerText);
        }
        if(maxVal < parseInt(value.innerText)){
            maxVal = parseInt(value.innerText);
        }
        console.log(index + ': ' + parseInt(value.innerText));
    })
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of getting the min and max values from an array which than you can use their values for your needs.

```js
getMinMax = (arr) => {
  return { min: Math.min(...arr), max: Math.max(...arr) }
}

const { min, max } = getMinMax([10, 1, 100, 120])

console.log(`min: ${min}, max: ${max}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create `max` and `min` variables and check, if current value is big from `max` and assign it to `max` and for `min`, if current value is small then `min`

```
var min = 1;
var max = 0;
var activeChoose = $('.filter--active-container').find('span[data-filter-param*="sFilterProperties"]');
  activeChoose.each(function (index, value) {

  if (!$($('.filter--active-container').find('span[data-filter-param*="sFilterProperties"]'))[index].attributes.style) {
   $(this).each(function (fakeIndex, value) {
   console.log(index + ': ' + parseInt(value.innerText));
   var v = parseInt(value.innerText);
   max = max > v ? max : v;
   min = min > v ? v : min;
})}});
```